# Get position of object in flask query .all()

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I would like to know how can I get the position of some object in a list of objects from flask sqlalchemy.

```
universities = University.query.order_by(University.students_total.desc()).all()

print universities
[<University 38>, <University 34>, <University 19>, <University 33>]
```

Let's say I want to get the position of the University 19

I've tried this, without success:  `universities.index("<University 19>")`

```
ValueError: '<University 19>' is not in list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by querying for a university and then finding the index of that university in your list of all universities. This could look something like this:

```
selected_university = University.query.filter_by(id=19).first()
universities.index(selected_university)
```

The problem with your previous code was that printing a list of all universities displayed the string representation of each object. You were then trying to find the index of one of those string representations. This didn't work because the actual list contained objects, not strings.